# textContent Value different in view than in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase

Okay this is kinda peculiar problem that I've never had before. I'll try to keep to quick and explain it as simply as possible. I have a page where a user can add and view some notes. Whenever someone clicks on a note, it opens a `modal container` to view the entire note. It finds the note using the `closest` method and then the content and the id of the note are passed to the modal container. Now whenever a user views a note (Say note A), the modal shows the content and id of note A. And if the user updates it (an update command is sent to firebase), the note does indeed gets updated. Works perfect. But if they now open note B, the modal container for some reason doesn't show the content of note B. It shows the content of note A for some reason. The ID is still for note B. I checked the Element tab in the debugger and the DOM does indeed gets updated with the correct content and id in the modal container, however on the webpage view the content is still rendered from note A for some reason.

The attached image would explain better:

[image]

Here's my code : It won't run completely here because it requires a user logged into firebase but I just need help on the modal container part. This is just for reference. Thanks a ton in advance!

PS: If I refresh the page obviously modal container picks the right value because the list was probably updated or something.

```html
<body>

    <div class="modal-container">
        <div id="background"></div>
        <div class="modal">
            <button class="modal__btn">&times;</button>
            <button class="modal__btn_b">Save</button>
            <!-- <h2 class="modal__title">Title bere</h2> -->
            <textarea id="modal__body">iis fugit possimus minus, repellendus dolores aliquid?</textarea>
            <textarea class="note__id">id should be here</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>




  

    <textarea id="todo-input" placeholder="Create a new todo..."></textarea>
    <button onclick="addItem(event)">Add</button>

    <div class="todo-items-wrapper">
        <div class="todo-items">
            <div class="todo-item">
                <div class="check">
                    <div class="check-mark checked">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="todo-text checked">
                Cut the lawn
            </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const todoitems = document.querySelector('.todo-items');
    const modalContainer = document.querySelector('.modal-container');



    function updateItem(notecontent, noteidd) {


        //   todoitems.innerHTML=""
       // event.preventDefault();

        //console.log(noteidd)

        let text = notecontent;
        let newItem = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection('notes').doc(noteidd).update({

            content: text,
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())

        })

    }

    function getItems() {

        var uid = null;

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                uid = user.uid;
                firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection('notes').orderBy("createdAt", "desc").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                    let items = [];

                    //   let itemsHTML = ""
                    let todoItems = []
                    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                        items.push({
                            id: doc.id,
                            ...doc.data()
                        })
                    })
                    generateItems(items);
                })

            }
        })}

    function generateItems(items) {
       
        todoitems.innerHTML = ""

        items.forEach((item) => {
            const itemsHTML = document.createElement('div');
            itemsHTML.classList.add('item');
            itemsHTML.innerHTML = `
        <span class="span__id">${item.id}</span>
    
    <span class="note__body">${item.content}</span>
    
    <div class="note__btns">
      <button class="note__btn note__view">View Detail</button>
      <button class="note__btn note__delete">Delete Note</button>
    </div>
        `;

     todoitems.appendChild(itemsHTML)

        })

      
    }



    window.onload = getItems();





   
    todoitems.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        if (e.target.classList.contains('note__view')) {
            const currentNote = e.target.closest('.item');
            const currentID = currentNote.querySelector('.span__id').textContent;
            const currentBody = currentNote.querySelector('.note__body').textContent;
           
            activateNoteModal(currentBody, currentID);
        }
    })




    function activateNoteModal(bodyy, noteid) {

        const modalBody = document.getElementById('modal__body');
        modalBody.textContent = bodyy;

        const note_id = document.querySelector('.note__id');
        note_id.textContent = noteid;

        modalContainer.classList.add('active');

 
    }



    const modalBtn = document.querySelector('.modal__btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
        modalContainer.classList.remove('active');
    })

    const modalSaveBtn = document.querySelector('.modal__btn_b').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        
        e.preventDefault();

        const notecontent = document.getElementById('modal__body').value;
      
        const noteidd = document.querySelector('.note__id').value
        updateItem(notecontent, noteidd);
    })


</script>
```

Ahmed's recommendation edit: `

```
      todoitems.querySelectorAll('.note__btns').forEach(btn =>

            btn.addEventListner('click', e => {

                if (e.target.classList.contains('note__view')){
                    
                const currentNote = e.target.closest('.item');

                const currentID = currentNote.querySelector('.span__id').textContent;
                const currentBody = currentNote.querySelector('.note__body').textContent;
                // Other code...
                activateNoteModal(currentBody, currentID);
            }}));`
```

Updated Ahmed's Snipped:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.note__btns').forEach(btn =>

   btn.addEventListner('click', (e) => {

const currentNote = e.target.closest('.item');

const currentID = currentNote.querySelector('.span__id').textContent;
const currentBody = currentNote.querySelector('.note__body').textContent;
// Other code...
activateNoteModal(currentBody, currentID);
  }));
```

Comment: you should be using document.querySelectorAll   not todoitems.querySelectorAll

Comment: Just tried it. Like legit nothing's happening upon clicking the button. Am I misunderstanding something? Pardon my ignorance, I'm still learning everyday.

Comment: remove this condition  if (e.target.classList.contains('note__view'))

Comment: you are checking for something that will always resolve to false

Comment: I see what you're saying. I just tried removing that condition. I put the updated snipped as an edit. Still not working. :(

Comment: Okay I tried logging the currentID and currentBody in console and it's not returning anything. So the code probably missed smth?

Comment: I added a working snippett of the code

Comment: the issue was in the classname .note_btns doesn't exist at your code\

Comment: it should have been  ".note_btn" without the s   Please don't copy & paste examples of code but try to implement the idea of them will help you in learning more and more about the code

Comment: I figured that it was that extra s but I did try it as .note__btn. Didn't work. I'm looking at your snippet right now.

Comment: Maneeee, I just went through the entire thing and tried it accordingly. Still not working. It's almost like my code is just skipping though this forEach loop. Like I don't get any interaction or info in the console whatsoever. any chance you'd be able to look at it via chat or something?

Comment: sure give me discord id

Comment: @AhmedGaafer it should just be '@Mansidak'

Comment: and the # number

Comment: #2328 my bad sorry

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet above you are selecting  the '.todo-items' class

and adding the click event on it which is not correct you are selecting the whole list and the .closest() will always resolve in the first item

what you should do is select all `note__btns` and add the click listener on all of them  using forEach

ex:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.note__btn').forEach(btn => 
 btn.addEventListner('click', e => {
  const currentNote = e.target.closest('.item');
  // Other code...
}));
```

The `currentNote`  here should resolve to the parent of each element hence getting the correct value

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.note__btn.note__view').forEach(elem =>{
 elem.addEventListener('click', e => {
   const currentNote = e.target.closest('.item');
   const currentID = currentNote.querySelector('.span__id').textContent;
   const currentBody = currentNote.querySelector('.note__body').textContent;
   
   activateNoteModal(currentBody, currentID);
  })
})


function activateNoteModal(body, id){
  console.log("Body =>>", body);
  console.log("ID =>>", id);

}
```

```html
<div class="todo-items">
  <div class="item">
    <span class="span__id">1</span>
    <span class="note__body">a</span> 
    <div class="note__btns">
      <button class="note__btn note__view" >View Detail</button>
      <button class="note__btn note__delete">Delete Note</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="span__id">2</span>
    <span class="note__body">b</span> 
    <div class="note__btns">
      <button class="note__btn note__view" >View Detail</button>
      <button class="note__btn note__delete">Delete Note</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I tried adding it like this:  
todoitems.querySelectorAll('.note__btns').forEach(btn =>
                btn.addEventListner('click', e => {
                    if (e.target.classList.contains('note__view')) {       
                    const currentNote = e.target.closest('.item');
                    const currentID = currentNote.querySelector('.span__id').textContent;
                    const currentBody = currentNote.querySelector('.note__body').textContent;
                    activateNoteModal(currentBody, currentID);
                }})); 

but I'm not getting anything now.

Comment: Shoot Let me add it in the question as an edit it looks nasty in the comment